# Rails 4 strong parameters syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clippo2/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...:user_id => [1], :instructions, :max_duration, :active, :max... ... ^
```

From this method while trying to implement the Rails 4 strong parameters:

```
  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:user_id => [1], :instructions, :max_duration, :active, :max_videos, :hashed_id)
    end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ty to remove the `=> [1]` after the `:user_id` OR use `.permit({:user_id => [1]}, :instructions, #etc...`

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji. I thought the `{` was optional.

Comment: It's only optional if the hash is at the very end of the argument list.

Comment: Gotch. Thanks. @MrYoshiji If you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I posted my answer, you can accept it, thanks @Emerson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the "`=> [1]`" after the `:user_id` symbol:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:user_id => [1], :instructions, :etc)                                              ^^^^^^^
params.require(:project).permit(:user_id, :instructions, :etc)
```

Or if you want to keep it, use `{ }`:

```
params.require(:project).permit({:user_id => [1]}, :instructions, :etc)
```

Or use ruby syntax parser to your advantage (see more info below):

```
params.require(:project).permit(:instructions, :etc, :user_id => [1])
```

---

This is actually a ruby feature. The latest arg given to a method is implicitly a Hash, therefore you don't need the curly braces `{` and `}` *on the latest arg* object.

For example, calling a method like this:

```
permit(1,2,3, :some => :var, :of => :a, :ruby => :hash)
```

Is the exact same thing as doing:

```
permit(1,2,3, { :some => :var, :of => :a, :ruby => :hash })
```

But passing the args in a different order would break the parser if the hash is first without the curly braces `{` and `}`.

Comment: @MSC this is actually a ruby feature. The latest arg given to a method is implicitly a Hash, see my update for examples.